# Convert Excel workbook to a CSV in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am getting an error in my VBA script for converting an Excel Workbook to a CSV. The VBA script is ran through a Microsoft Word VBA script.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim wb_xl As Excel.Workbook
Dim wb As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb_xl = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("O:\documents\folder.xlsx")
wb_xl.SaveAs FileName:="O:\documents\folder.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("O:\documents\folder.csv")
wb_xl.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

This seems straight-forward and the CSV is being produced, but I am receiving an error:

> Run-time error '1004': Cannot access 'folder.csv'

The error is on Line 8 (`wb_xl.SaveAs...`).

Comment: Looks like you might be saving the file as `"C:\folder.xlsx"`.  Try `wb_xl.SaveAs FileName:="C:\folder.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Comment: I actually did not use the C-drive, I used a work network drive but showed it differently here for the sake of simplicity. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Matthew- apologies, that was a copy-paste error. I am saving it as with the csv extension - see edit.

Comment: Not really what you're asking about but....   Isn't "wb" a worksheet?  You're setting a worksheet to a workbook object when you open the .csv file.  I've never tried setting a worksheet to a workbook object, but that seems like it's the wrong object to be using...

Comment: Also, a standard practice is to make sure that the directory or file exists before trying to access it.  In your case, adding a check and creating the directory if it doesn't exists would be a really good idea.  I would even apply that logic prior to the 2 "Open" calls.  One more silly question:  Are you sure that you have "Write" access to that location?

Comment: If you do a `SaveAs` isn't that now the active workbook? Can't open it if it's already open.

Comment: but i think @FrankBall is correct.... probably ought to rename `wb` to `ws` to avoid confusion and change the Open to the actual workbook object

Comment: @FrankBall correct, but that's a *type mismatch* error that would be thrown right after the workbook is opened.

Comment: When I type in ```?Dir("O\documents\folder.csv") ``` I do not receive an error. It prints ```folder.csv```.

Comment: Open Task Manager and make sure that you don't have any other instances of Excel running in the background.  You may have opened a copy of this file and it's being held onto in memory.

Comment: @FrankBall when I closed out the background processes of Excel the code worked.

Comment: When you're debugging and kill the code, you can leave stray instances of Excel behind.  Make sure that you check for them any time you have to break your code.  Also make sure that you clean them up in your code as well (objExcel.Quit).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
> ```

If this isn't causing any problems now, it will be later. Split the declaration and the assignment, avoid auto-instantiated objects in general, but even more especially for objects that spawn an external process when created.

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
```

...and don't forget to `.Quit` that instance when you're done:

```
'...
objExcel.Quit
```

Now, error 1004.

> ```
> wb_xl.SaveAs FileName:="O:\documents\folder.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
> ```
>
> *This seems straight-forward and the CSV is being produced*

The unqualified `xlCSV` constant is no biggie, but keep in mind that it's only valid because the `Excel` library is referenced; consider qualifying it:

```
wb_xl.SaveAs FileName:="O:\documents\folder.csv", FileFormat:=Excel.xlCSV
```

If the CSV is being produced, then the `SaveAs` call worked, and the failing statement would be this one:

> ```
> Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("O:\documents\folder.csv")
> ```

You can't `Open` that file, it's already opened - that's why the statement is throwing error 1004: if you tried it in the Excel UI with a .xlsm file, you'd be getting a more detailed error message:

[image: Sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time]

But the error message is different with a .csv file:

[image: Run-time error 1004: Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Dev\test123.csv. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?]

I got this error message by typing this in the immediate pane, with a new blank workbook opened:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Dev\test123.csv", xlCSV
Set b = Workbooks.Open("C:\Dev\VBA\test123.csv")
```

I think that's exactly the error you're getting.

Remove `wb`, you don't need it (note: if the `Open` succeeded, the assignment would be throwing a *type mismatch* error, because you can't assign a `Workbook` object to a `Worksheet` reference; `Dim wb As Excel.Worksheet` looks wrong). Remove the `Workbooks.Open` operation too, the CSV is already opened.

In other words:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    Dim wb As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("O:\documents\folder.xlsx")

    wb.SaveAs FileName:="O:\documents\folder.csv", FileFormat:=Excel.xlCSV
    wb.Close savechanges:=False

    xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: The CSV may already be opened, but if she is only exporting one sheet out of multiple sheets (which is what the SaveAs to csv does), she may only want to see that single sheet.  Even if she did a SaveAs, until the file is closed and re-opened, the other sheets ares still available.  If that's the case the copying the sheet in question to new file and then doing the SaveAs would be the way to handle having only the one sheet available without having to close the file and then re-open it.

Comment: @FrankBall fair enough, but OP isn't iterating any worksheets in that workbook, so either there's only 1 sheet, or the code isn't doing what it needs to do (or it's just lucky to always just have the correct sheet active when it opens)... but there's no indication in the OP that this would be the case, and this answer shows a clear repro for OP's error 1004, plus a solution.

Comment: She wouldn't have to iterate through the sheets, Excel only takes the first sheet when you do SaveAs to csv.  If her file is aggregating data from multiple sheets on the first sheet, a SaveAs to csv would a easy way to get the data into a nice tidy generic package for other applications to access.

Comment: @FrankBall no. If there are multiple sheets with exportable data, saving as CSV through the UI [prompts whether to only export the active sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCaHG.png). From VBA code, no prompt - but only the `ActiveSheet` (that is not necessarily the first sheet) is exported to CSV.

Comment: You're right, it is only the active sheet that gets exported.  The user that I support who does this kind of thing has always made sure that the first sheet was the one being exported and I just followed along with his assumption.  I'm now .0002% smarter than I was yesterday.